# Azure Linux Webapp cannot seem to find deployed Spring .jar from DevOps repo

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-devops, yaml

I have a Spring Web Application in a DevOps repository, with a .yml that looks like this (as generated by the tool in the DevOps web client):

```
# Build your Java project and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

trigger:
- master

variables:
  Version: '0.0.1'


  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: '-snipped-'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'SlackCentralTestApp'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'SlackCentralTestApp'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: MavenPackageAndPublishArtifacts
    displayName: Maven Package and Publish Artifacts
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: Maven@3
      displayName: 'Maven Package'
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        publishJUnitResults: true
        testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
        mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
        mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
        effectivePomSkip: false
        sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to artifact staging directory'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        Contents: '**/target/SlackbotTest-$(Version)-SNAPSHOT.?(war|jar)'
        TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployLinuxWebApp
    displayName: Deploy Linux Web App
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool: 
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: SlackCentralTestApp'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Azure for Students (4998490e-1bc4-43fc-a370-80744706d1f5)'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              appName: 'SlackCentralTestApp'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/target/SlackbotTest-$(Version)-SNAPSHOT.jar'
              runtimeStack: 'JAVA|11-java11'
              startUpCommand: 'java -jar $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/target/SlackbotTest-$(Version)-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

The deployment process seems to be successful [as seen in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLxTH.png), yet when I take a look at the server log, I sadly get greeted with the following error:

```
2020-04-14T09:03:55.658599508Z Initializing App Insights applicationinsights-agent-codeless-2.5.0.jar....
2020-04-14T09:03:55.669449167Z STARTUP_FILE=
2020-04-14T09:03:55.676322304Z STARTUP_COMMAND=java -jar /home/vsts/work/1/drop/target/SlackbotTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2020-04-14T09:03:55.676350305Z No STARTUP_FILE available.
2020-04-14T09:03:55.676428905Z Running STARTUP_COMMAND: java -jar /home/vsts/work/1/drop/target/SlackbotTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2020-04-14T09:03:55.681352232Z Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/vsts/work/1/drop/target/SlackbotTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2020-04-14T09:03:55.694784805Z Finished running startup command 'java -jar /home/vsts/work/1/drop/target/SlackbotTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'. Exiting with exit code 1.
```

This would lead me to conclude that the path as given in the 'startUpCommand' property from the .yml file is incorrect, yet I have not been able to find what the correct path should be.

I have attempted the following:

1. Specify no directories, only the filename. Leads to the same result, sadly.
2. Use the 'find' command in Bash to find any .jars on the Web App, which tells me that there are none.

Manually building the application from the Web App does not seem to be an option either, as it's a Java 11 application and the java SE that seems to be included is version 1.8, regardless of the version I specify during the creation of the Web App resource in Azure.

Comment: `$ (Pipeline.Workspace)` refers to the folder path on the agent, your app has been deployed to the azure web app service, you should specify the path of the jar on the Azure web app service in the startup command.

Comment: I see, but how can I determine the path on the web service? When I try to find any .jars using the Bash environment, it shows me no results.